# OpenVPN client config :: why is needed ca.crt?

Tags: encryption, vpn, openvpn

I configured a VPN (OpenVPN, mode: multiclients-1server),
CentOS Server, multiple Rasp's clients.

CA.crt is needed by each client, in addition of the client.crt & client.key .

I wonder... why ? What is ca.crt here for ?

Answer (score 0):

This file usually contain the certification authority root keys and it is required for check validity of certificate (of client and server). It is used to check the entire chain of certificates

Comment: Thank you @Romeo, I understand. But why the need to put it  by the client side ? Server should check with its own ca.crt

Comment: To make similar check from client site :)

Comment: ;) allright. Isnt it quite sensitive to distribute ca.crt to clients ?

Comment: Not at all. If you check public CA you will see there all the root certificates. Do not forget that certificate is signed public key :) And all the server software I know (web, mail, application) want to have your certificate, your key and entire certificate chain up to top root certificate to be able to serve SSL/TLS